# XHR requsests by ajax through 403 error after about 1 minute

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

When I make a request for web page content (chatlog) in a short time it troughs a 403 forbidden error: Access to this resource on the server is denied!

Here is my AJAX code

```
      var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
        {
               $.ajax({
                url: "chatlog.html",
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $(".chatbox").html(html);
                }
                });

        }, 10); // refresh every 10 milliseconds
```

Please help, I have been working on this for hours

EDIT: I fixed it

Comment: If you refresh that often you'll overwhelm the server and it might block you. Probably the previous request hasnt even completed before you start a new one. Reduce the refresh frequency to maybe every 30 seconds or so, you might get away with that, although under load of many users it might still be bad.  Ajax is a legacy technology choice for writing real-time chat applications in a browser (it was never a good choice but for a while it was pretty much the only one). Use websockets instead for 2-way real-time interaction with the server

Comment: 10 ms is too small, I usually refresh my web content every 3 seconds if it's really necessary. otherwise only when some event occurs.

Comment: @ADyson how would I do that?

Comment: Do what? I made a couple of suggestions. If you're talking about websockets it's too broad a topic for a single comment, or even a single answer to give you a ready made solution, but there are plenty of tutorials etc out there, and plenty of implementations of websocket servers, including  a couple written in php